# Generic C Tcp Server Memory Leak

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, pthreads, posix

My posix tcp servers all seems to be leaking. I'm keeping an eye on them with tools like ps and top and they think that the memory is constantly increasing. 
It happens whenever a client is entering and/or leaving.

Eg. let's say that ps reports 100 VSZ at first. A client enters and it rises to 238. The client then exits and it drops to 138. *Not 100*! Every time a client enters and exits the memory is increased.

I've tried a ton of different memory leak tools like eg. valgrind and none of them finds anything. (And they don't think it's leaking either.)

Is it ps and top that're confused? It seems unlikely.

I've made a small generic sample that demonstrates my code and the potential leak:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 100*1024

void* server_process_thread(void* args)
{
    int client = (int)args;
    unsigned char* buffer = NULL;
    int r;

    /* allocate something huge */
    if((buffer = malloc(MAX_BUFFER)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't allocate");
        goto exit;
    }

    printf("Client processing ...\n");

    //echo all that comes
    while(1)
    {
        r = read(client, buffer, MAX_BUFFER);
        if(r <= 0) break;
        write(client, buffer, r);
    }

exit:
    printf("Client exit\n");
    free(buffer);
    close(client);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_sockaddr = {0};
    struct sockaddr_in clientSockAddr = {0};
    int flags = 1;
    int server = 0;
    int client = 0;
    pthread_t thread = 0;
    socklen_t clientSockSize = sizeof(clientSockAddr);

    //init tcp
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);

    if ((server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open socket");
        return -1;
    }

    flags = 1;
    if ((setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *) &flags, sizeof(flags))) == -1)
    {
        perror("Couldn't set socket reuse");
        return -1;
    }

    server_sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sockaddr.sin_port = htons(666);
    server_sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //IP

    if (bind(server, (struct sockaddr *) &server_sockaddr, sizeof(server_sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Couldn't bind socket");
        return -1;
    }

    //LISTEN
    if (listen(server, SOMAXCONN) == -1)
    {
        perror("Couldn't listen on socket");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("TCP Echo Server started ...\n");

    //wait for clients
    while(1)
    {
        client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*) (&clientSockAddr), &clientSockSize);

        if(pthread_create(&thread, NULL, server_process_thread, (void*)client) != 0)
        {
            perror("Couldn't create thread");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //dispose
    printf("Server exit\n");
    close(server);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, I might miss some error handling here and there, but is there some fundamental flaw in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are leaking threads,  at least.

By default, pthreads are not "cleaned up" when it exits until someone calls pthread_join() on it.

If you create the thread as a detached thread, its resources will be cleaned up when it exits (but you can no longer pthread_join() it). 
The easiest way to do this is to call `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` as the first thing in your `server_process_thread`.

Comment: I thought I had already tried that but it seems to be working when added to the sample.